# Removing Alphanumeric Words, With Some Exceptions in Python 3

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to clean up some bodies of text in Python 3 by removing alphanumeric words (words which contain both letters and numbers), but there are a few exceptions I'd like to remain in the text. The following code removes all alphanumeric words from the text:

```
import re

string1 = "3n3k game gnma34 xbox360 table"
string2 = "the a22b b3kj3 ps4 2ij2aln potato"

new_string1 = re.sub(r'\w*\d\w*', '', string1)
new_string2 = re.sub(r'\w*\d\w*', '', string2)
```

The above code produces new_string1 which is "game table", and new_string2 which is "the potato". What I need is for new_string1 to be "game xbox360 table" and new_string2 to be "the ps4 potato".

I figure I can create an array of exceptions, e.g.:

```
exceptions = ['xbox360', 'ps4'] #there may be many more exceptions than this
```

but am not too sure how to incorporate this list of exceptions into my regular expression (I'm fairly new to the concept). Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if that solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a two-way approach: split and analyze the words:

```
import re

strings = ["3n3k game gnma34 xbox360 table", "the a22b b3kj3 ps4 2ij2aln potato"]
exceptions = ['xbox360', 'ps4']

def cleanse(word):
    rx = re.compile(r'\D*\d')
    if rx.match(word) and word not in exceptions:
        return ''
    return word

nstrings = [" ".join(filter(None, (
    cleanse(word) for word in string.split()))) 
    for string in strings]
print(nstrings)
# ['game xbox360 table', 'the ps4 potato']
```

---

Additionally, I changed the regular expression to

```
`\D*\d`
```

and try to match them at the beginning of each "word" (with `re.match()`) as `\w` contains digits as well.

---

If you are able to upgrade to the [**newer `regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/), you could use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and a better expression without the need of a function:

```
\b(?:xbox360|ps4)\b   # define your exceptions
(*SKIP)(*FAIL)        # these shall fail
|                     # or match words with digits
\b[A-Za-z]*\d\w*\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/t2nFHG/2/) and the complete `Python` snippet here:

```
import regex as re

strings = ["3n3k game gnma34 xbox360 table", "the a22b b3kj3 ps4 2ij2aln potato  123123 1234"]
exceptions = [r'\d+', 'xbox360', 'ps4']

rx = re.compile(r'\b(?:{})\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b[A-Za-z]*\d\w*\b'.format("|".join(exceptions)))

nstrings = [" ".join(
    filter(None, (rx.sub('', word) 
    for word in string.split()))) 
    for string in strings]
print(nstrings)
# ['game xbox360 table', 'the ps4 potato 123123 1234']
```

Comment: I ended up using your second suggestion, implementing the regex module. Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hm, I am encountering one issue now that I test it in practice. I'm wanting to keep words that are wholly numbers (e.g.: 123123) and wholly words (e.g.: potato). With this method, words that are wholly numbers like 123123 are removed. Any advice on how to prevent that?

Comment: @Rudy: Of course, you can add regular expressions as an exception as well, see the `r'\d+'` in the exceptions list (have updated the answer).

Comment: Ah, didn't even think of that! Works great, thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative lookahead. A negative lookahead is *zero-length*: it does not match anything; it either succeeds or fails, and, after it is done, the cursor is still where it was before. So, you want to check for a word boundary (`\b`), check that the following text isn't in your exceptions list (`(?!...)`), and use your existing regex to match the word (`\w*\d\w*`).

To construct the body of the lookahead, simply concatenate the elements of `exceptions` together with a `|` in between, or just make `exceptions` a regex that matches words that you want to keep directly.

I don't have much familiarity with Python, so here's what the regex should look like in the example case, and I hope you can generalize:

```
\b(?!xbox360|ps4)\w*\d\w*
```

To remove white spaces

```
" ".join(re.sub(r'\b(?!xbox360|ps4)\w*\d\w*'," ",string1).split())
```

Comment: I have tried this but unfortunately not getting required output  `>>> string1 = "3n3k game gnma34 xbox360 table"
>>> re.sub('\b(?!xbox360|ps4)\w*\d\w*'," ",string1)
'3n3k game gnma34 xbox360 table'`

Comment: Odd: https://repl.it/NW4v/0. Did you forget the `r`? It does have whitespace problems, but you version had them too, so I assumed you'd sort them out yourself later.

Comment: Yes sorry, missed `r`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find regular expression for you but here is one way to achieve it

```
>>> exceptions = ['xbox360', 'ps4']
>>> string1 = "3n3k game gnma34 xbox360 table"

>>> " ".join([i if i in exceptions else re.sub(r'\w*\d\w*', '', i) for i in string1.split()])
' game  xbox360 table'
>>> string2 = "the a22b b3kj3 ps4 2ij2aln potato"

>>> " ".join([i if i in exceptions else re.sub(r'\w*\d\w*', '', i) for i in string2.split()])
'the   ps4  potato'
```